# How to use php functions with prototypejs?

Tags: javascript, php, html, prototypejs

How can I use php functions in the update-function of prototypejs?
I made a little code to show my problem:

```
<div id="rand_num">Click the button to get a new random number!</div>
<button name="number" type="button" onclick="updateRandom();">
      <p><b>Generate new number!</b></p>
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateRandom(){
        $('rand_num').update('WHAT DO I HAVE TO PUT HERE??');
    }   
</script>

<?php
    function getRandNum(){
        return rand(0,20);  
    }
?>
```

Everything in this script everything works, but I would like to call the function "getRandNum()" and paste the generated number at every button action to the div *rand_num*.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: to get a Javascript function to call a PHP function you would probably need to investigate making an Ajax call to the server http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to do this.

First, you could pass the value in directly when PHP draws the page

```
function updateRandom(){
    $('rand_num').update('<?php echo getRandNum() ?>');
}
```

Second could be done via AJAX

```
function updateRandom(){
    new Ajax.Request('/another/php/file.php', {
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            $('rand_num').update(transport.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Just make your PHP file call that function and echo it out.